# Schwarzschild metrics form a smooth one-parameter family of smooth metrics.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, wave-equation, general-relativity

In my lecture notes, they claim that the family of Schwarzschild metrics form a smooth one-parameter family of smooth metrics, but the proof of this is left to the reader as an exercise and I am struggling with convincing myself of it.

Let $(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ denote the standard coordinatees on $\mathbb{R}^{3+1}$ and $r= \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$. Then consider for fix $R>0$ the manifold $\mathcal{M}_R=\{r>R\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{3+1}$. Now we can consider on $\mathcal{M}_R$ the family of metrics with parameter $M\in (-\infty,R/2]$ given by $$ds^2= -(1-2M/r)dt^2+(1-2M/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2).$$

I would like to show that this forms a smooth one-parameter family of smooth metrics (and are Ricci flat).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DIdier_ Hey Dldier, I have tried to come up with a smooth map $\phi:U \to E$, where $U$ is some open set and $E$ our family, to no avail. Do you have any tips on where to start? Thank you

Comment: Write $g_r = -(1-2M/r)dt^2+(1-2M/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$. It is a Lorentzian metric when $r > M/2$ (exercice: show this). Write $L$ the set of Lorentzian metrics on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then $r \in (M/2,+\infty) \mapsto g_r \in L$ is the desired map: $(g_r)_{r>M/2}$ is a smooth family of Lorentzian metrics! The hidden difficulty is to show that "smooth" has meaning here, that is, $L$ has a structure of a manifold. This is because it is a certain subset of a certain space (the space of sections of $S^2T^*\mathbb{R}^4$ + required symmetries and signature).

Comment: @Didier Thanks a lot!! I misunderstood the construction of the family and thus missed this rather simple construction. Many thanks.